Formula for sum of values in a solution to a linear system
Consider the linear system $A x = b$, where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with positive determinant. This system has a unique solution $x$. I am interested in the sum of values in the solution, $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$. Is there a formula for this sum, as a function of $A$ and $b$?
I can use Cramer's rule to compute the value of every $x_i$, and then sum all the values, but this results in a long and cumbersome formula. Is there a way to simplify it?
In case this matters: I am particularly interested in the case in which the entries of $A$ are all either 0 or 1, and the entries of $b$ are all 1.
EDIT: If there is no simple formula, are there at least simple upper and lower bounds on the sum (as a function of $A,b$)?

We have $x=A^{-1}b$, and $A^{-1}$ has an easy form for your binary matrices. For example, for the one of size $7$ with determinant $32$ from your previous post , it is $$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 &-1 & -1& 1 &-1 \cr -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1\cr 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \cr -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \cr -1 & -1 & 1 & -1& 1 & 1 & 1 \cr 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1& 1 & 1 \cr 1 & 1  & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ Then $x=A^{-1}b=\frac{1}{4}b$ for $b=(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)$. So $\sum_{i=1}^7 x_i=\frac{7}{4}$.

@DietrichBurde OK, but I am looking for a general formula (as a function of A,b)

The only way for a general answer, I think, is your referred Cramer's rule but it would be cumbersome as you have said. Examples like the given by Dietrich Burde are beatiful particular cases.

Let $A\in \mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$ and invertible matrix, and $b\in \mathbb{K}^{n\times 1}$. We can write :
$$x=A^{-1}b$$
For convinience sake, let's $B=A^{-1}$ the inverse of $A$ and $\underline{B}_j\in\mathbb{K}^{1\times n}$ the $j\text{th}$ row of $B$. Such that
$$x_j = \underline{B}_jb$$
Then, the sum of all $x_j$ is given by :
$$\sum_{j=1}^n x_j = \sum_{j=1}^n \underline{B}_jb$$.
Beware, that $\underline{B}_jb$ is the dot product of the $j\text{th}$ row of $B$ by $b$.

Note that this is equivalent to $cA^{-1}b$ where $c=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&\cdots&1\end{bmatrix}$
